# Why is this not working in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm having problems with the jQuery stuff for IE8.

It works well in Firefox and Safari, but not IE8. http://www.ninjasliveclancodes.com/

When I click bump or add code, it doesn't show the error messages. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works here fine..looks like a cache problem, not a code problem.  Try exiting, clearing cache and going another round with it.

Comment: I already cleared cache. Could it have something to do with me being on Windows Home Server OS?

Comment: @Doug - It might, it IE is running in enhanced security mode it will block javascript on most sites by default.  It's like this on other server editions...but I haven't used Home Server personally.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here also I agree with Nick, maybe you need to clear your cache.